# How to pass 2 PasswordBoxes as CommandParameter to Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, multibinding, passwordbox

In WPF, PasswordBox.Password is not a DP, so we can't directly bingding it in ViewModel. I have done an online search, use this methods, but the converter just is called one time when the view is loaded, so the parameter in ExecuteMyCommand is null:

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <DockPanel x:Name="WindowLayout" LastChildFill="False">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="PasswordBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="PswBox" Grid.Column="1" Height="27"/>
            <TextBlock Text="PasswordBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="AgainPswBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="27"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Click" Width="60" Margin="10">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{cvt:PlainMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="PswBox"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="AgainPswBox"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Converters\PlainMultiValueConverter.cs

```
namespace MVVM_Light_Base.Converters
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(PlainMultiValueConverter))]
    //[ValueConversion(typeof(object[]), typeof(object))]
    public class PlainMultiValueConverter : MarkupExtension,
        IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public static PlainMultiValueConverter converter = null;

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (null == converter)
            {
                converter = new PlainMultiValueConverter();
            }
            return converter;
        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel\MainViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace MVVM_Light_Base.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private RelayCommand<object> myCommand;

        public RelayCommand<object> MyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return myCommand ?? (myCommand =
                    new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteMyCommand));
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteMyCommand(object parameter)
        {
            var pswBoxes = parameter as object[];
            PasswordBox pb;
            string psw0;
            string psw1;

            try
            {
                pb = pswBoxes[0] as PasswordBox;
                psw0 = pb.Password;
                pb = pswBoxes[1] as PasswordBox;
                psw1 = pb.Password;
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Why the converter didn't work perfectly? And how should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning array from the converter, **convert array into new list** and pass from the converter.

**Converter**

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
   return values.ToList();
}
```

**Command Method**

```
private void ExecuteMyCommand(object parameter)
{
   var pswBoxes = parameter as List<object>;
   .....
}
```

Comment: It's perfect. But I don't know why need to 'return values.ToList()'?

Comment: By passing values directly, you are actually passing reference to array. So, any change in array will reflect across its usage. Not sure which action set the objects back to null (might be some code in XAML loading). So with `ToList()` you are creating new reference and passing that to ViewModel which won't change on any update in value array.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually the problem is in your Converter. You don't need to implement MarkupExtension. Just IMultivalueConverter.

```
public class PlainMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then declare your converter as a resource in your XAML and use it as a simple `{StaticResource MyConverter}`.

```
<DockPanel x:Name="WindowLayout" LastChildFill="False">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <local:PlainMultiValueConverter x:Key="PlainMultiValueConverter"/>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
<!--...-->
    <Button IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Click" Width="60" Margin="10">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PlainMultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="PswBox"/>
                <Binding ElementName="AgainPswBox"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: PlainMultiValueConverter inheriting MarkupExtension just implements singleton pattern.